# Problem with reducer function in useReducer hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reducers, use-reducer

The reducer function works fine except that previously added  object element to the `item` array property gets over written whenever new object element is added.
For example, if `state.item` contains `{number: 1}` and I add `{number: 2}`, it becomes `[{number: 2},{number: 2}]` instead of `[{number: 1},{number: 2}]`.

The reducer function:

```
const reducer = (state, action) => {
  if (action.type === "ADD") {
    let newItem = state.item.concat(action.addItem);

    console.log("action.addItem:", action.addItem);
    console.log("state.item:", state.item);
    return { item: newItem };
  }
};
```

Is there any solution this problem?

Thank You.

Parent Component:

```
import React from "react";
import { useReducer } from "react";
import { CreateContext } from "./CreateContext";

const initialState = {
  item: [],
};

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  if (action.type === "ADD") {
    let newItem = state.item.concat(action.addItem);

    console.log("action.addItem:", action.addItem);
    console.log("state.item:", state.item);
    return { item: newItem };
  }
};

const AuthProvider = (props) => {
  // define useReducer
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  // define handlers
  const addItemHandler = (addItem) => {
    console.log("addItemHandler");
    dispatch({ type: "ADD", addItem: addItem });
  };
  const data = {
    addItem: addItemHandler,
    number: 0,
    item: state.item,
  };

  return (
    <CreateContext.Provider value={data}>
      {props.children}
    </CreateContext.Provider>
  );
};
export default AuthProvider;
```

Child component:

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from "react";
import {
  Button,
  Card,
  CardActionArea,
  CardActions,
  CardContent,
  CardMedia,
  makeStyles,
  Typography,
  Collapse,
  TextField,
  IconButton,
} from "@material-ui/core";
import clsx from "clsx";
import AddBoxIcon from "@material-ui/icons/AddBox";
import { Grid } from "@material-ui/core";
import { CreateContext } from "../Store/CreateContext";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  card: {
    marginBottom: theme.spacing(5),
  },
  media: {
    height: 250,
    // smaller image for mobile
    [theme.breakpoints.down("sm")]: {
      height: 150,
    },
  },
  priceDetail: {
    marginLeft: theme.spacing(15),
  },
  numberTextField: {
    width: 52,
  },
  addBtn: {
    fontSize: 60,
  },
}));

const data = {
  id: null,
  name: null,
  price: null,
  quantity: null,
};

// img and title from the feed component
const Food = ({ img, title, description, price, id }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  // expand the description
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState(false);

  const handleExpandClick = () => {
    setExpanded(!expanded);
  };

  const newPrice = `RM${price.toFixed(2)} `;

  ////// process the form //////
  //get quantity from TextField
  const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState("");
  const quantityHandler = (enteredQuantity) => {
    console.log("enteredQuantity:", enteredQuantity);
    setQuantity(enteredQuantity.target.value);
  };
  // use useContext
  const AuthData = useContext(CreateContext);

  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    console.log("submit is pressed");
    e.preventDefault();
    data.id = id;
    data.title = title;
    console.log("data.id:", data.id);
    data.price = price;
    console.log("data.price:", data.price);
    data.quantity = quantity;
    console.log("quantity:", quantity);
    AuthData.addItem(data);
    console.log("AuthData:", AuthData.number);
  };

  return (
    <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
      <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
        <Card className={classes.card} id={id}>
          <CardActionArea>
            <CardMedia className={classes.media} image={img} title="My Card" />
            <CardContent>
              <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5">
                {title}
              </Typography>
              <Button
                size="small"
                color="primary"
                className={clsx(classes.expand, {
                  [classes.expandOpen]: expanded,
                })}
                onClick={handleExpandClick}
                aria-expanded={expanded}
                aria-label="show more"
              >
                Learn More
              </Button>
              <CardActionArea>
                <Collapse in={expanded} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
                  <CardContent>
                    <Typography paragraph>{description}</Typography>
                  </CardContent>
                </Collapse>
              </CardActionArea>
            </CardContent>
          </CardActionArea>

          <CardActions>
            {" "}
            <Typography variant="h6" className={classes.priceDetail}>
              {newPrice}
            </Typography>
            <Typography variant="h6" className={""}>
              x
            </Typography>
            <TextField
              id={id}
              label="amount"
              type="number"
              // value={}
              // onChange={}
              className={classes.numberTextField}
              label=""
              variant="outlined"
              min="1"
              max="5"
              step="1"
              defaultValue="0"
              size="small"
              onChange={quantityHandler}
              input={id}
              // ref={quantity}
            />
            <IconButton aria-label="" onClick={""} type="submit">
              <AddBoxIcon
                color="secondary"
                className={classes.addBtn}
              ></AddBoxIcon>
            </IconButton>
          </CardActions>
        </Card>
      </form>
    </Grid>
  );
};

export default Food;
```

Comment: Can you give us some more context on this? There's nothing I see in your reducer which could cause this problem, and from the description it seems likely that you're mutating existing state before you call the reducer - but you don't show us where it's actually called (`addItemHandler` does the dispatch, but this is passed in context and you don't show us any components that use this).

Comment: Sorry for not explaining in detail. Yes, the userReducer hook is in the parent component, and there is a child component that calls the `addItemHandler`.As far as I know the, child component simply passes 'addItem' object as an argument for the  `addItemHandler`, so it doesn't mutate the existing state. I'll add the child component in the question just in case.

Comment: Thanks, and I see the problem now - it's not something I would have expected at all. Going to write it up in an answer, give me a few minutes!

Comment: I've spent many hours trying to debug this so I don't mind waiting for a few minutes at all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is entirely in your child component, and nothing to do with your reducer. It's how you are passing in the data that becomes the `addItem` payload in the action you dispatch.

I have reproduced below the relevant parts of the child component (or rather the whole module), so you can see the problem more clearly:

```
const data = {
  id: null,
  name: null,
  price: null,
  quantity: null,
};

const Food = ({ img, title, description, price, id }) => {
  // more code that isn't relevant here

  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    console.log("submit is pressed");
    e.preventDefault();
    data.id = id;
    data.title = title;
    console.log("data.id:", data.id);
    data.price = price;
    console.log("data.price:", data.price);
    data.quantity = quantity;
    console.log("quantity:", quantity);
    AuthData.addItem(data);
    console.log("AuthData:", AuthData.number);
  };

  // more code that isn't relevant here
}
```

The `data` that you are passing to `AuthData.addItem` (that ends up being passed to the reducer) isn't a new object each time - it's a single "global" (module-level) constant that you simply mutate each time you use it. This is what's causing your state to mutate - because each object that ends up in the array of your `state.items` is a reference to that same object, so each mutation you make (inside `submitHandler`) ends up changing every copy!

You can easily fix this in the child component, by not simply mutating the same object each time but recreating a new one. I don't see any reason for what you are doing, so simply stop doing it! I would rewrite it as below:

```
// note NO const data = ...

const Food = ({ img, title, description, price, id }) => {
  // more code that isn't relevant here

  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    console.log("submit is pressed");
    e.preventDefault();
    const data = {};
    data.id = id;
    data.title = title;
    console.log("data.id:", data.id);
    data.price = price;
    console.log("data.price:", data.price);
    data.quantity = quantity;
    console.log("quantity:", quantity);
    AuthData.addItem(data);
    console.log("AuthData:", AuthData.number);
  };

  // more code that isn't relevant here
}
```

Doing it this way, each object in the state "item" array will be unique, and you can dispatch new ones without affecting the old ones!

Comment: Thank you so much! I had no idea there was a problem with the child component.